# Trouble with OADataFetcher on iPhone when using URL Encoded strings

Tags: iphone, oauth, urlencode

I'm using OAuth/xAuth in an iPhone twitter app, and having a problem with passwords that contain special characters. For example "password&". First off, I am converting the & into %26 by doing:

```
NSString *encodedPassword = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                 NULL,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)thePassword,
                                                                                 NULL,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

This encodes it fine into "password%26". I am then setting it up as a parameter of an OAMutableURLRequest:

```
    [request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [OARequestParameter requestParameterWithName:@"x_auth_mode" value:@"client_auth"],
                        [OARequestParameter requestParameterWithName:@"x_auth_username" value:encodedUsername],
                        [OARequestParameter requestParameterWithName:@"x_auth_password" value:encodedPassword],
                        nil]];
```

Upon sending the request using an OADataFetcher, I receive an NSUrlError:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 UserInfo=0x4823e00 "Operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"

What am I doing wrong here? If I leave the & in the password it crashes my code (the setParamaters array flunks out). Has anyone come across this before using OAuth?

If I have a alphanumeric password everything works fine... Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

OAuthRequestParameter already encodes the name and value; it may be that the & in particular is causing problems. Have you tried using different non-standard characters? It might required modifying the OAuth library itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the standard OAuth libary using the buggy stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding to encode the username and password.

My solution was to make a category to override the following methods in OARequestParameter

```
 - (NSString *)URLEncodedName 
{
 return [self.name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSString *)URLEncodedValue 
{
    return [self.value stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

i.e:

Put the following somewhere in your project:

```
//the .h file
#import "OARequestParameter.h"

@interface OARequestParameter (YourApp)

@end
```

and override the buggy methods with:

```
#import "OARequestParameter+YourApp.h"


@implementation OARequestParameter (YourApp)

-(NSString*)encode:(NSString*)unencodedString
{
 NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                       NULL,
                       (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                       NULL,
                       (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
 return [encodedString autorelease]; 
}

- (NSString *)URLEncodedName 
{
 //return [self.name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 return [self encode:self.name];
}

- (NSString *)URLEncodedValue 
{
    //return [self.value stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 return [self encode:self.value];
}

@end
```